# How can I use a Request class for storing and updating?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a class Request for my Room table.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' =>  ['required', 'unique:categories', 'string'],
            'fr' => ['required', 'string']
        ];
    }
```

It uses the "Rule" class to insure that the request as an unique name, but also allows the name to be input again if it is an update request.

However, I have some questions :

- If my request is a store and not an update, will it break the thing ? If so, how can I avoid it breaking ?
- How can I get the $id to my special Request class ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to attach that room request in both of your update and store method in your controller.

Now, in your store method should look like this. Same with your update method

```
public function store(RoomRequest $request)
 {
     // your code here. 
 }



public function update(RoomRequest $request, $id)
 {
     // your code here. 
 }
```

Now in your rules, to prevent your validation to show the error of unique when yo are updating, you should use ignore method of validator, see code below.

```
public function rules()
{
      return [
           'name' =>  ['required', Rule::unique('categories')->ignore($this->id), 'string'],
           'fr' => ['required', 'string']
       ];
}
```

Don't forget to attach it above your code

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
```